# How to make lightcase plugin work with .webp?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox, lightcase.js

I am using https://cornel.bopp-art.com/lightcase/

When using .jpg etc.

```
<div id="lightcase-content">
  <div class="lightcase-contentInner" style="opacity: 1; width: 700px; max-width: 100%;">
    <img src="/upload/big/tresna.jpg" style="max-width: 850px; max-height: 500px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

When using .webp image the output is in the `<iframe>`

```
<div id="lightcase-content">
  <div class="lightcase-contentInner" style="opacity: 1; max-width: 100%;">
    <iframe src="/upload/big/tresna.webp" style="width: 800px; height: 500px; max-width: 850px; max-height: 500px;">
      <html>
      <head>
      <body>
        <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8085/upload/big/tresna.webp">
      </body>
      </html>
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to use .webp but i'd like it to display like when using .jpg (Without iframe)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just find typeMapping in the script and add webp so it looks like:

```
typeMapping: {              
'image': 'webp,jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp',   
},
```